# Why isn't this simple jQuery script working?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a very basic HTML5/jQuery rotation script. Here is the code:

```
$(document).find("[data-rot]").each(function(i, e) {
        var rotation = $(this).attr("data-rot");
        console.log(i+' '+rotation);
        $(this).css({ '-moz-transform': rotation, '-webkit-transform': rotation });
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div data-rot="90">Rotate me 90 degrees</div>
<div data-rot="20">Rotate me 20 degrees</div>
<div data-rot="180">Rotate me 180 degrees</div>
<div data-rot="300">Rotate me 300 degrees</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? The console.log() works.

Comment: No error, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Why aren't you simply looking for `$('[data-rot]')`? Also, you can access `[data-]` attributes using the `data` function within the `each` function: `$(this).data('rot')`.

Comment: does the `console.log()` produce any output? Also, what browsers are you testing with? And what versions?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just a number, try setting the values of the transform properties to `rotate(90deg)` and so on. There are many more CSS transform functions than just rotation, see more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform#CSS_transform_functions).

Comment: Care to expand a bit? Please?

Comment: I added a link which will provide some useful and interesting information about CSS transformations. Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use: `$(this).css({ '-moz-transform': rotation+"deg", '-webkit-transform': rotation+"deg"})`

Basically, you need to set the rotation as "xdeg", rather than "x"